# Awk using shell variable to grep string

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I have tried below but it is printing multiple lines even the string pattern doesn't match. Any wrong in that?

I have input file `infile1.txt` which has strings in it.
I have a fixed file containing `1000` lines `fixfile.txt` in which string is present.

I want to find out few strings as per the requirement.

cat infile1.txt

```
Iam_happy
excited.abouttrip
Travelling is passion
```

Cat fixfile.txt

```
John said iam_happy today
Tom was excited.abouttrip
Chick is delicious
I love cartoon
.... 
.
.
```

Output expected

```
John said iam_happy today
Tom was excited.abouttrip
```

Shell Script Tried

```
while read line
do
grep $line /home/fixfile.txt > output1.txt
done < infile1.txt
```

Comment: Without seeing samples it is nearly impossible to understand it correctly, kindly do add samples of input and expected output in your post.

Comment: Have you look at the `-f` option to `grep`? Your loop isn't necessary. [grep(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)

Comment: Edited for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -Fif infile1.txt fixfile.txt > output1.txt
```

`F` for matching fixed strings,
`i` for matching case-insensitively,
and `f` for specifying the pattern file.